# strange behaviour for $_GET

Tags: php, html, variables, get, global-variables

I have a multidimensional language site. When calling a page that does not exist, `.htaccess` will refer to `404.php` in the root direction.

The `.htaccess` looks like that:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

That `404.php` in the root direction simply looks which default language is set by a `SESSION` or `COOKIE` and refers to the language subdirection `/language/404.php`

The root `404.php` looks like that:

```
include_once "scripts/pref_language.php";

if (isset ($_GET['uri']) === true ){
    $get = $_GET['uri'];

    header("Location: /$pref_language/404.php?uri=$get");
    exit;
}

$url = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

header("Location: /$pref_language/404.php?uri=$url");
```

Refered to the language subdirection, the posted `URL` looks like that:

```
http://www.example.com/english/404.php?uri=somedata
```

or with an other language:

```
http://www.example.com/german/404.php?uri=somedata
```

The code of `/english/404.php` looks like that:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();
session_start();
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

include_once "../scripts/db_connect.php";
include_once "../scripts/functions.php";
include_once "../scripts/browser_identification.php";
include_once "../scripts/pref_language.php";

...some text variables in its specific language

include_once "../templates/template_404.php";
?>
```

The template is just some `HTML` styling. The Footer that will be included in the `template_404.php` is the main attraction to send data. In that Footer there is the option to change the language setting and switching between the language paths. If a `form` will be submitted the `SESSION` and `COOKIE` will be changed and the page starts a header-function.

So here is the Code from the Footer:

```
if (isset($_GET['uri']) ) {
    $uri = urlencode($_GET['uri']);
    echo "TEST URI: $uri";
}

$en_dir = '../en/';
$de_dir = '../de/';
$fr_dir = '../fr/';
$pl_dir = '../pl/';
$tr_dir = '../tr/';

...

$basename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php"); 

if ($basename === "index") {
    $form_action = rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php');
} else{
    $form_action = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

...

if ( isset($_POST['pref_lang']) === true ) {

    $content = $_POST['pref_lang'];

    if ($content === "de") {

        if ($basename === "about") {
            $basename = "info";
        } else if ($basename === "contact") {
            $basename = "kontakt";
        }           
    }
    $_SESSION['pref_language'] = $_POST['pref_lang'];

    setcookie('pref_language', '', time()- 999999, '/', '.example.de' );
    setcookie('pref_language', $content, time()+60*60*24*365, '/', '.example.de');

    if ($basename === "404"){

        header("Location: ../$content/404.php?uri=$uri");

    } else {

        header("Location: ../$content/$basename");  
    }
}
?>
<div id="data">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <form action="<?php echo $form_action;?>" method="post">      
                    <input type="submit" id="de" name="pref_lang" value="de"/><label for="de">german</label>
                </form>
            </li>

            <li>
                <form action="<?php echo $form_action;?>" method="post">  
                    <input type="submit" id="fr" name="pref_lang" value="fr"/><label for="fr">french</label>
                </form>
            </li>

            <li>
                <form action="<?php echo $form_action;?>" method="post">  
                    <input type="submit" id="pl" name="pref_lang" value="pl"/><label for="pl">polish</label>
                </form>
            </li>

            <li>
                <form action="<?php echo $form_action;?>" method="post">  
                                        <input type="submit" id="tr" name="pref_lang" value="tr"/><label for="tr">turkish</label>
                </form>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

The problem is that when a page has the `URL` of

```
http://www.example.com/**english**/404.php?uri=somedata
```

and I will submit `$_POST` to change the language to german like:

```
http://www.example.com/**german**/404.php?uri=somedata
```

for example `$_GET['uri']` will be empty and the URL looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/**german**/404.php?uri=
```

after starting header function. Instead of header I tried to echo out that line and I will receive a message that `uri` is not defined.

```
Undefined variable: uri in /customers/7/4/1/example.com/httpd.www/scripts/footer_en.php on line 102
Location: ../english/404.php?uri=
```

The strange about that is that when I will call the page before sending `$_POST` and have a look at the source code of the site the variable `$uri` will read out the `$_GET` parameter correctly but later on it does not work anymore in the header function?

So it would be nice if someone can tell me what to do to fetch this issue. I really would appreciate.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Why arbitrarily stop at two levels of boolean comparison? Why not `if (((isset($_GET['uri']) === true) === true) === true)`?

Comment: sorry, i did not get it. can you explain a little bit further?

Comment: You don't need to compare the return value of `isset` strictly to a boolean value which will produce another boolean value which `if` then evaluates. `isset` already returns a boolean, just `if (isset(...))` is perfectly fine. Just a coding style nitpick.

Answer (score 0):

Add the uri to your form action before using it in your forms.

```
$form_action .= "?uri=" . $uri;
```

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. when adding this it causes the error that $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will be the same URL as before. The changes on SESSION/COOKIE takes effect but the language dir will not be changed because of the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']